# Construct a graph of nodes using adjacency list in Python

Tags: python, graph, nodes, adjacency-list

I have a `Node` class as below

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, val = 0, neighbors = None):

        self.val = val
        self.neighbors = neighbors if neighbors is not None else []
    
    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return all([other.val == self.val, self.neighbors == other.neighbors])
        
        return False
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Node(val: {self.val}, neighbors: {self.neighbors})"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()
```

I am trying to construct a Graph using an adjacency list as below:

```
[
 [2,4],
 [1,3],
 [2,4],
 [1,3]
]
```

In the above adjacency list that is indexed from `1`, the index is the `Node` value i.e. `Node.val` and the list at that index are the neighbors i.e. `Node.neighbors`

For e.g., for index 1:

```
Node.val = 1
Node.neighbors = [Node(2), Node(4)]
```

For index 2:

```
Node.val = 2
Node.neighbors = [Node(1), Node(3)]
```

and so on ...

How can I construct the Graph using python, where I want to consider the `Node` represented by index=1 in the adjacency list to be it's entry point i.e. the root.

Basically a function that returns the root of the Graph:

```
def make_graph(adj_list: List) -> Node:
    ...
```

I have tried iterative approach, resulting in infinite loops or wrong output.

One of my attempts that resulted in wrong output:

```
def make_graph(adj_list: List) -> Node:
        
        if not adj_list:
            return []
        
        root = Node(1)
        node_dict = {}
        
        for i in adj_list[0]:
            neighbor = Node(i)
            root.neighbors.append(neighbor)
            node_dict[i] = neighbor
        
        node_dict[1] = root
        
        for i in range(1, len(adj_list)):
            
            node = Node(i) if i not in node_dict else node_dict[i]
            
            for neighbor in adj_list[i]:
                
                if neighbor not in node_dict:
                    neighbor_node = Node(neighbor)
                    node_dict[neighbor] = neighbor_node
                else:
                    neighbor_node = node_dict[neighbor]
                
                node.neighbors.append(neighbor_node)
                
            if i not in node_dict:
                node_dict[i] = node
                
        return root
```

Which gives the output:

```
Node(
    val: 1, 
    neighbors: [
        Node(
            val: 2,
            neighbors: [
                Node(
                    val: 2,
                    neighbors: [...]
                ),
                Node(
                    val: 4,
                    neighbors: []
                )
            ]
        ),
        Node(
            val: 4,
            neighbors: []
        ),
        Node(
            val: 1,
            neighbors: [...]
        ),
        Node(
            val: 3,
            neighbors: [
                Node(
                    val: 1,
                    neighbors: [...]
                ), 
                Node(val: 3,
                     neighbors: [...]
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Any kind of help or pointing in the right direction is immensely appreciated.

Comment: Since your graph has cycles, what is the expected output you *do* want to have?

Comment: @trincot I am actually trying to make a test case runner for this [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/clone-graph/), where I want to convert the given input adjacency list to a Node root and pass it to the solver function. I wonder how leetcode is converting the list to a Node root to run their own tests.

Comment: OK, so you want to mimic what LeetCode does before it calls your solution code.

Comment: @trincot yes, precisely that. I want to mimic how leetcode is transforming the adjacency list into a root Node of a Graph (interconnected `Node` instances). I want to take that root Node and give it to my automated tests to determine if an input (adjacency list) is generating the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be easier if you first create all the node instances, and then populate the neighbors, by mapping those neighbor numbers to the nodes you will then have at your disposal.

Here is a function you could use:

```
def make_graph(adj_list: List) -> Node:
    nodes = [Node(i + 1) for i in range(len(adj_list))]
    for i, neighbors in enumerate(adj_list):
        nodes[i].neighbors = [nodes[j-1] for j in neighbors]
    return nodes[0]
```

Code to test this with the example input:

```
from typing import List

class Node:
    def __init__(self, val = 0, neighbors = None):
        self.val = val
        self.neighbors = neighbors if neighbors is not None else []

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Node(val: {self.val}, neighbors: {self.neighbors})"

def make_graph(adj_list: List) -> Node:
    nodes = [Node(i + 1) for i in range(len(adj_list))]
    for i, neighbors in enumerate(adj_list):
        nodes[i].neighbors = [nodes[j-1] for j in neighbors]
    return nodes[0]

adj_list = [[2,4],[1,3],[2,4],[1,3]]
node = make_graph(adj_list)

print(node)
```